# How to add element to a HashSet while iterating this HashSet?

Tags: java, hashset

I have a use case like following:

```
SET is a Set of Integer with size N
for i in SET (I mean only iterate the Set of size N at start point):
    if i + 7 not in SET:
        SET.add(i + 7)

return SET
```

How to implement this using Java HashSet except using an auxiliary list/set to store the element which needs to be inserted?

Comment: As written, if there are any elements in SET, this would run for forever

Comment: @lucasvw It will be `concurrent modification exception`

Comment: Well yes, but my point is if we ignore that, the set would grow infinitely. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @lucasvw Yes, I know. What I want to say is only iterating over the SET at starting point

Comment: @lucasvw: Why should that run forever? Given that it would work at all (it will not), the insertion has to happen behind the current cursor position (perhaps at the end) to make it running indefinitely. But if the insertion point is at be beginning (before the first entry), it will terminate nicely. For a hash based `Set` (the most commonly used), the new value could be inserted anywhere, before or after the current cursor position, so the behaviour would be completely unpredictable. But as it does not work at all, this discussion is hypothetic …

Comment: Could you use a LinkedList instead of a set? Then you could use a ListIterator

Comment: @lucasvw Since I want to use O(1) to check whether `i + 7` exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to add something to the `Set` instance while iterating over its contents; when using the `foreach` loop (`for( var e : set )` notation), no modification is allowed, while when using an explicit iterator (`for( var i = set.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) …` notation), you can call `i.remove()` to get rid of the current element. But adding new elements does still not work in this case.

This behaviour is shared by all Java Collection classes, although `List` knows a special iterator class, `ListIterator`, that also allows adding entries (notation `for( var i = list.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) …`) by calling `i.add()` – thanks to @lucasvw for reminding me on that.

Comment: With a list iterator you can add elements, but OP specified using a Set

Comment: Thank you! I never know that `listIterator` has such a property.

Answer (score 2):

@lucasvw eluded to the underlying issue here - you need to somehow differentiate between the original values and the values you've added, otherwise, the loop will run indefinitely (or, at least, until the values overflow enough so they start repeating themselves).

The best way to do this is to indeed have an auxiliary set to hold all the values you want to add:

```java
Set<Integer> aux = original.stream().map(i -> i + 7).collect(Collectors.toSet());
original.addAll(aux);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to make a copy yourself, Java can do that for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html. It will not be faster or anything magical, but you can iterate "the original" and modify at the same time.

However if you want something efficient, that is presumably to create another `Set` with the new elements, and [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) them at the end. Depending on the size of the set it may be faster to skip the containment-check, and leave it for the merging.

[`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) and its `or()` operation may be also something to look at if your numbers are nonnegative and are of low magnitude.